# How to get same value in batch start method

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I am working on batch class. I am sending data from `trigger`.I am sending `Trigger.new` in batch. When i debug in constructor i can see all field but when i check debug in batch start method i am not able to see all field.

I have a field name is opp_image__c and that field available in constructor but can't see in start method.

opp_image__c field type is `rich text area`

```
 if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        // execute batch for update property image
        Database.executeBatch(new BatchImageInsert(Trigger.new), Limits.getLimitCallouts());
    }
```

**Batch class**

```
global class BatchImageInsert implements Database.batchable<Opportunity> , Database.stateful {

    global List<Opportunity> opp;

    //Constructor
    public BatchImageInsert(List<Opportunity> newOpp) {
        system.debug('opp in constructor');
        system.debug(newOpp);
        opp = newOpp;
        system.debug(opp);
    }     

     //Start Method for batch with database.querylocater return type
    global Iterable<Opportunity> start(Database.BatchableContext info) {
        system.debug('opp in start');
        system.debug(opp);
        return opp;
    } 

    //Execute method  
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Opportunity> scope) {
        system.debug('scope');
        system.debug(scope);
    }

    //Finish Method
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is this the only field or it is a random behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer in my mail. `Trigger` show all field. but when we access in start method that time we can't see some field that field have `null` value.